# does my file stay open or closes automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this piece of code :

```py
    features_dict = json.load(open(features_path))
```

I want to know if my file stays open after the execution or if it closes automatically ?

Comment: It stays open. You should close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file stays  open and you need to close it or use `with open` and it will close automatically after going out of scope:

```
with open ('features_path','r') as features_path:
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: I wasn't sure. Thanks for the insight. Is there a simple way to test if a file stays open?

Comment: Should be `as features_path:` (or some other variable name) without  quotes

Comment: @Steven yes, after running your initial command run `features_dict = json.load(features_path)` without opening the file and it should still read the data

Comment: @Daniil I meant, using my piece of code. Is there a way I can check that my file is still open, so I do not do the same mistake again ?

Comment: @Steven add `features_dict = json.load(features_path)` to the bottom of your code, if it is closed it will return an error